# remove lines that contain IP range from specific column while making exclusions to range

Tags: command-line, awk, sed, text-formatting

I have a logfile with the following format:

```
Jul 13 21:47:41 192.168.100.254 "user from 192.168.100.101"
```

I need to remove ALL lines that contain IP's in the 192.168.x.x range but only if they appear in the 4th column.

I also need to exclude 3 IP's from the 192.168.x.x range. Lets call these

```
192.168.125.100
192.168.126.100
192.168.155.240
```

How can I finish this command to find all the IP's in the 192.168.x.x range in the 4th column and remove all the lines except the ones that contain 192.168.125.100, 192.168.126.100, and 192.168.155.240.

```
awk '{print $4}' file | grep '192.168' | "remove all found except" | > save back to original file
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '{f=1} $4 ~ /^192.168/{f=0} $4 ~ /192.168.(125.100|126.100|155.240)/{f=1} f' file
```

#### Example

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
Jul 13 21:47:41 192.168.100.254 "user from 192.168.100.101"
Jul 13 21:47:41 192.168.125.100 "user from 192.168.100.101"
Jul 13 21:47:41 192.168.126.100 "user from 192.168.100.101"
Jul 13 21:47:41 192.168.155.240 "user from 192.168.100.101"
Jul 13 21:47:41 123.456.789.240 "user from 192.168.100.101"
```

As I understand your rules, you want to keep all but the first line above.

```
$ awk '{f=1} $4 ~ /^192.168/{f=0} $4 ~ /192.168.(125.100|126.100|155.240)/{f=1} f' file
Jul 13 21:47:41 192.168.125.100 "user from 192.168.100.101"
Jul 13 21:47:41 192.168.126.100 "user from 192.168.100.101"
Jul 13 21:47:41 192.168.155.240 "user from 192.168.100.101"
Jul 13 21:47:41 123.456.789.240 "user from 192.168.100.101"
```

#### Multiline version

For those who prefer their code spread over multiple lines:

```
awk '
  {
    f=1
  }

  $4 ~ /^192.168/ {
    f=0
  }

  $4 ~ /192.168.(125.100|126.100|155.240)/ {
    f=1
  }

  f
  ' file
```

#### How it works

The code uses a single variable `f`.  If a line should be kept, we set `f=1`.  Otherwise, `f` is set to zero.

- `f=1`

  To begin, assume that the line should be kept.
- `$4 ~ /^192.168/{f=0}`

  If `$4` starts with `192.168`, then mark the line as one that we should lose.
- `$4 ~ /192.168.(125.100|126.100|155.240)/{f=1}`

  For these three special cases, mark the line as a keeper: `f=1`.
- `f`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for: if `f` is true (nonzero), then print the line.

#### Additional testing

As per the comments, we will try file2:

```
$ cat file2
Jul 13 21:47:41 192.168.100.125 "user from 192.168.100.101"
Jul 13 21:47:41 192.168.202.150 "user from 192.168.100.101"
Jul 13 21:47:41 192.168.101.45 "user from 192.168.100.101"
```

Now, let's run our command:

```
$ awk '{f=1} $4 ~ /^192.168/{f=0} $4 ~ /192.168.(125.100|126.100|155.240)/{f=1} f' file2
$
```

All these lines were removed as they should be.

Comment: No, I need to remove ALL the lines in the 4th column that have 192.168..x.x while only keeping the lines that have 192.168.125.100, 192.168.126.100
and, 192.168.155.240. I ran your command and although it looks to be right according to your description, It does not work. When I run it I still see lots of lines that should not be there.

Comment: @user53029 Hmm.  That is not good.  Please show me a few sample lines that appear in the output but shouldn't.

Comment: 192.168.100.125, 192.168.101.45, 192.168.202.150, etc..

Comment: The only lines I expect to see are 192.168.125.100, 192.168.126.100, and 192.168.155.240

Comment: Interesting...I can get it to work using a test file as well but it does not work using my actual file. I'll update my question and post the lines.

Comment: I got it. Your command was working. Brain fart on my end. Thanks!

Comment: Very good.  Glad its working.

Comment: could be simplified to `awk '$4 ~ /192.168.(125.100|126.100|155.240)/ || $4 !~ /^192.168/'` ... also, may be add a note that `.` should be `\.` for matching dot literally.. (not needed as such for given input format)